# Convert GNU find command to Python function

Tags: python, bash

I want to convert this GNU command into a python function:

```
find folder/ 2>/dev/null > file.txt
```

The find will list all files and folders from the directory recursively and write them
to a file.

What I have now in Python is:

```
import os
project="/folder/path"
i=0
for (project, dirs, files) in os.walk(project):
   print project
   print files
   i += 1
```

But now I am trying to make the output exactly as find does.

Comment: Have you read about `os.walk` yet?  After reading that, please update your question to be specific.  This is not "write code for me.com"

Comment: Thank you, I am sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 4):

```
import os
path = "folder"
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    print(dirpath)
    for filename in filenames:
        print(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
```

Instead of `print` you can write to file.

Comment: Thank you, this is the correct solution. I was using 
print project
if len(files) > 0:
 print files
i += 1

but it wasnt joining them.

Thank you.

Comment: One more thing please, some files are not r-x by everyone or other errors while reading, how can I prevent in Python their inclusion ? (2>/dev/null from find)